# Clear contents of specific selected listview rows?

Tags: excel, vba, listview, userform

I've been trying to create an event for my application.

I want to be able to click on a row and after selecting this row, click on my 'delete button' and delete the row from my `listview`, and from my spreadsheet.

I have tried using the `ClearContent`  and the `Remove`  properties but neither of them worked and I got different errors such as *Type mismatch (Error 13)*.

These are my code snippets tryouts:

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click()
    
    ListViewEntries.ListItems.SelectedItem.Remove
    
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click()
    
    ListViewEntries.SelectedItem = ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click()
    
    ListViewEntries.SelectedItem.ClearContents(i)
    
End Sub
```

Not sure where the problem is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click()        
    ListViewEntries.ListItems.Remove ListViewEntries.SelectedItem.Index        
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click()        
    Call ListViewEntries.ListItems.Remove(ListViewEntries.SelectedItem.Index)
End Sub
```

The the call means:

```
ListViewEntries.ListItems.Remove(IndexOfItemToRemove)
```

Take the list box `ListViewEntries` go into the `ListItems` and `Remove` something. Now `Remove` needs an agrument **what** to remove. This argument is an index of an item in the list box. Since you want to remove the selected item you need to submit the index of the selected item `ListViewEntries.SelectedItem.Index` as parameter to the `Remove` method.

Comment: Hello friend! I tried your code and it works but as soon as I refresh my listview the row is still there. The same thing with my spreadsheet. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: This only removes an item from the list view itself but it does not manipulate any worksheet data! This would be a completely different question. Therefore you would need to ask a new question and show how you fill the list box with data.